# Can I create EL in the Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

What I want to do is "Once I login to webpage, I want to show related user name and role (eg Silvia As Admin)"

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <div class="simplenav">
                    <form action="login.jsp">
                        <div id="Logdiv">
                            <button type="button" id="btnLogout" value="Logout"> Logout </button>
                            <button type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Login"> Login </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>         
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

```
.done(function(data){
    if(data.status == 200){
      $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
      $("#btnLogin").hide();
      $("#btnLogout").show();
      $("${requestScope.users.empName} As ${requestScope.users.role}").prependTo($("#Logdiv"));
   }
   else
      alert("Invalid Login Id and Password.");
   })
```

This part doesn't work ....
$("${requestScope.users.empName} As ${requestScope.users.role}")

If I put "hi" instead of that, it works well...

In my servlet is ....request.setAttribute("users", emgr.Find(Integer.parseInt(userid)));

I'm struggling with that ... Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is a little off. You want to create an element and prepend it to your Logdiv - but you aren't creating the element.

`.done(function(data){
    if(data.status == 200){
      $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
      $("#btnLogin").hide();
      $("#btnLogout").show();
      var el = '<div>' + requestScope.users.empName + ' As ' + requestScope.users.role + '</div>'; //this creates your element with the user info in it
      $(el).prependTo($("#Logdiv"));
   }
   else
      alert("Invalid Login Id and Password.");
   })`